# Making two connected select fields is super ugly, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am pulling data from the server side (ATM I'm still using the FixturesAdapter) and want to make two connected select inputs for the user to pick and choose one of the pulled formats. Every format has a category that it belongs to, so the first input makes the user choose a category, and then the second select input updates to only include the formats from the before selected category.

I've managed to make it work, but the code looks really messy and ugly, is there a way to improve it?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

*Format Model*

```
App.Format = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.attr('string')
});
```

*ApplicationRoute*

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('formats').set('model', this.store.find('format'));
    }
});
```

*formats.hbs*

```
<label class="control-label">Category:</label>
<div class="controls">
    {{view "select" content=categories value=selectedCategory}}
</div>
<label class="control-label">Format:</label>
<div class="controls">
    {{view "select" content=formats value=selectedFormat}}
</div>
```

*FormatsController*

```
App.FormatsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    needs: 'index',

    categories: function() {
        return this.mapBy('category').uniq();
    }.property('@each.title'),

    observeCategories: function() {
        this.set('selectedCategory', this.get('categories.firstObject'));
    }.observes('categories'),

    observeSelectedCategory: function() {
        this.set('formats', this.filterBy('category', this.get('selectedCategory')).mapBy('title'));
    }.observes('selectedCategory'),

    observeFormats: function() {
        this.set('selectedFormat', this.get('formats.firstObject'));
    }.observes('formats'),

    observeSelectedFormat: function() {
        var format = this.findBy('title', this.get('selectedFormat'));
        this.get('controllers.index').set('format', format);
    }.observes('selectedFormat')

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - [Working JS Bin Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/womewuxuci/5/edit?html,js,output)

There are few things you are doing wrong here:

1. Your `ApplicationRoute.setupController` method is used to set the model for another controller. `setupController` is for setting up the **route's controller**. Moreover, when you override `setupController` it is better you call `this._super(controller, model)`, so ember will set `model` as `controller`'s model.
2. So, you need to implement `App.FormatsRoute` which will implement the `model` method and this is where you should return `this.store.find('format')`. No need to override `App.FormatsRoute.setupController` method for that.
3. `formats` should be a computed property which depends on `categories`
4. `{{view "select" content=formats value=selectedFormat}}`

   should be:

   `{{view "select" content=formats optionLabelPath='content.title' optionValuePath='content.id' selection=selectedFormat}}`

   `formats` should be a an array of `format` models. In this way `selectedFormat` will be populated with a format model, without you computing it by yourself.

Comment: I don't really need a separate route for formats, because the control only makes sense when it is used to set a format property of an another model. So I'll need to get a reference to an another controller, but  as far as I understand, I'll need to be using the "needs" system for that. I really appreciate the feedback, my main pain was to see if the `FormatsController` could be slimmed down drastically, because I was getting the feel, that I'm doing something completely wrong. Glad you showed some tricks with computed properties there!